# Facebook Development App

Tags: facebook

I have been trying for almost a week to install a Unity3d app/game on a Facebook page.  I'm probably one of 2 people on earth that is not that familiar with Facebook. I have had a Facebook Ad account for over a year. I think this might be the problem. I can't find any information if apps can even be added to Ad accounts.  Every post suggests adding the 'Development App' or a Canvas Page. These processes lead me back to my Ad page and there is no Dev App to install or links or canvas pages.  When I try to use the Developer Tutorial or the canvas tutorial clicks lead back to my ad page. On 'Ad Page' on the left side I have the following options....Campaigns and Ads, Pages, Reports, Settings, Billings, Creative Library and Learn More. I tried to open a regular account and deactivate the Ad Account, but could not get pass the phone number verification because I'd used my number to verify my first account.  So that one never got fully set up. I reactivated the Ad Account but still can't access the Development App or Canvas Pages or Open Graph. How can I ad the Development App to an Ad Account?

Comment: You should probably consult http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers as here on StackOverflow we help people out with coding problems.  As there no code here, it's kinda hard for us to help.

Comment: @DMCS Thanks I'll try that group! I'm really surprised that there is no active direct support system at Facebook.

Comment: Us too!  I rarely see Facebook devs on StackOverflow answering questions. Pretty sad actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer app, http://www.facebook.com/developers, stopped working for me a couple of weeks ago.  I think you're supposed to use https://developers.facebook.com/apps now.

Comment: That is the developers app :)

Comment: I beg to differ with your semantics, lix.  http://www.facebook.com/developers used to be known as the "developer app" but it doesn't work for some of us any more.  I would call "http://developers.facebook.com/apps" a developer website, not an "app".  But I don't really care what you call it.  I think Digital D just wanted to know where to go to do what needed to be done.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why you are not being redirected to the correct URL even when you are using the old one.  I land on the same page no matter which of the two URL's I use.  Perhaps you have uncovered a small bug in their systems :P